# Vagrant SSH Issues

Tags: windows, ssh, vagrant, virtualbox

When I run "vagrant up", it times out:

```
C:\Users\Natalie\remnux>vagrant up

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...

==> default: Checking if box 'bhaskarvk/remnux' is up to date...

==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...

==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...

==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...

    default: Adapter 1: nat

==> default: Forwarding ports...

    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)

==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...

==> default: Booting VM...

==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...

    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222

    default: SSH username: remnux

    default: SSH auth method: password

Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that

Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within

the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.
```

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.

After this, a vagrant status command comes back showing that vagrant is running. However, when I attempt to vagrant ssh it comes back with this:

```
C:\Users\Natalie\remnux>vagrant ssh

==> default: The machine you're attempting to SSH into is configured to use

==> default: password-based authentication. Vagrant can't script entering the

==> default: password for you. If you're prompted for a password, please enter

==> default: the same password you have configured in the Vagrantfile.

ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

One last thing, my professor mentioned that it might be an issue that I don't have an identityFile when I run the command vagrant ssh-config:

C:\Users\Natalie\remnux>vagrant ssh-config

```
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1

  User remnux

  Port 2222

  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null

  StrictHostKeyChecking no

  PasswordAuthentication no

  IdentitiesOnly yes

  LogLevel FATAL
```

I have tried getting this resolved with my professor and still came up against a wall. I am running Windows 10 Education on an Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6100U CPU @ 2.30GHz 2.30GHz Processor.

I have attempted to troubleshoot by adding on to the vagrantfile but that didn't appear to work either(not sure if I did it right).

This is my first time posting a question on here so I am not sure how much information is needed but I am willing to try whatever needs to be done to troubleshoot the issue. I guess my main issue is the fact that I do not know what the root of the issue actually is or if there are many things that are wrong.

Comment: What's in your `Vagrantfile`?

Comment: Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|  config.vm.box = "bhaskarvk/remnux"  end  @kichik

Comment: Do you have a firewall or AV running on Windows? Have you tried turning them off?

Comment: Yes, firewall was turned on. I have turned it off now. I restarted my computer and it still isn't working. @kichik

Comment: Have you tried using WireShark? It might supply some crucial hints.